# Bitbucket account invisible to Google?

Tags: bitbucket

I own a repository on Bitbucket; it is public, meaning that it is visible to anyone and indeed a friend of mine already made a fork.

However, I noticed that my entire account seems to be invisible to Google: even searching for the exact URL or large amount of its content does not bring to any result.

Why? How can I make it indexable by search engines (if that is the problem)?